# How to root Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge+?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-6-edge+

I've Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge+ (SM-G928i). I need to utilize Tor properly. I need root access. I do not have access to any sort of other computer.

How can I root this device without a PC?

Comment: Which Android version are you using? Have you tried anything so far which we should now avoid suggesting you?

Comment: It has lollipop 5.1.1,  Kernel architecture is aarch64.. no i have not tried as i have not had access to a pc since purchasing and will not for sometime

Comment: Even changing the os would be amazing but im assuming that requires root access